# How to solve race condition between js that manipulates iframe and iframe load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have got javascript file that checks whether iframe is loaded and if it is loaded then append some content to the iframe

body_application.js

```
var iframe_object = $('#embedded_document_container')
  .load(function(){
    $(this).contents().find('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/style.css"/>');
  });
```

But I noticed that this approach have a problem mentioned in below scenario 1.

**First scenario:**
I checked network log, iframe got loaded first then the script body_application.js that does modification to the iframe.

In this case it does not append style.css

**Second scenario:**
I checked network log, iframe got loaded after the script body_application.js that does modification to the iframe.

In this case it does append style.css

Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Can include `js` where `iframe` element is loaded into document ?

Comment: @Joseph If you see my description I have already used answer given in that post. My problem is that script that manipulates iframe loads sometimes before iframe is loaded or later. So $(element).load() does not work if iframe is loaded earlier before script is attached to the doc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code causes a so-called [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), where the outcome depends on external factors as they influence the speed of individual operations, in this case the loading speed of the subpage.

The easiest solution is to keep the `src` property of the `iframe` initially empty and then setting it *after* applying the onload event:

```
var iframe_object = $('#embedded_document_container')
  .load(function(){
    $(this).contents().find('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/style.css"/>');
  });
iframe_object.attr('src', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
```

This ensures automatically that the page can never be loaded before the event is in place.

You could use more complex solutions, like broadcasting messages from inside the iframe, or checking its load status and then conditionally setting the event, but the solution above is just most practical.

Comment: Yes. It seems like a neat approach. Let me see if that works for me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Worked like charm. :D

Comment: Yep , a neat and fine solution ,i am going to use it in my upcoming deals . Thanks  Niels from my side too :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be a superior or prior solution than this . But you may proceed  as below :-

When iframe load ,you may check continuously for checking the 'head' element ,if found you may do further stuff now and clear interval for looking up .

```
 var iframe_object = $('#embedded_document_container')
      .load(function(){
        var lookUp=setInterval(function(){
        if($(this).contents().find('head'))
        {
            $(this).contents().find('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/style.css"/>');
           clearInterval(lookUp);
        }
      },500);
      });
```

**CONDITION**
When your JS functions load later condition , check if iframe is already loaded..

```
var iframe_object = $('#embedded_document_container')
if(iframe_object.contents().find('body'))
{
//do directly--
}
else
{
//bind load event --
 iframe_object.load(function(){/*your codes*/});
}
```

Comment: Now it answers my question. Thanks. I will try it

Comment: Technically this could still cause a race condition, as the `iframe` will be loaded in a different process, and Javascript provides no serialization at that level. I'm not sure how the serialization of the load event is handled across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoadHandler() {
    alert('loaded');
}
</script>
```

```html
<iframe id ='myframe' src='www.mysite.com' onload="onLoadHandler();"></iframe>
```